# Workbox background sync [Empty Body]

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, background-sync

I'm using Workbox Background Sync in an internal React Progressive Web App (PWA) that is utilized by an average of 700 users per day. I employ background sync to handle file uploads on the app. For most requests, the process works well. When a user is offline while uploading their photo/document, the request is successfully stored in the indexedDB table and later replayed when the user regains network connectivity.

However, I am encountering an issue with a non-negligible portion of the requests. The request itself is stored correctly in the indexedDB table, but when I call my API to log the request, I observe that the request body is empty (screenshot provided below).

[image]

Do you have any ideas why the request body is null? We haven't encountered any issues with the original request, and the app has been thoroughly tested for almost a year now. It's important to note that we upload the file in Base64 format and do not use formData for file uploads :

Finally, here is the section of code responsible for cloning the requests:

```
const routesToRegister = [
{
    pattern: /.*\/file/,
    method: ['POST', 'DELETE'],
},
{
    pattern: /.*\/post_it/,
    method: ['POST', 'DELETE'],
},
{
    pattern: /.*\/report/,
    method: ['POST'],
},
{
    pattern: /.*\/arrival/,
    method: ['PATCH'],
},
{
    pattern: /.*\/product/,
    method: ['PATCH'],
},
];
routesToRegister.forEach((route) => {
  route.method.forEach((method) => {
    registerRoute(
        route.pattern,
        new NetworkOnly({
            plugins: [bgSyncPlugin],
        }),
        method,
    );
  });
});
```